# Cache Simulator

Tags: c, caching

I am writing a cache simulator. The idea is to given an input file with commands, trace the results of that input simulating cache functions so that we can keep track of cache hits and misses. I have written the following code but seem to be having trouble getting the proper output. I am posting my whole code because I dont want to make assumptions about where the problem may lie. Can anyone tell where I am making a mistake?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <strings.h>

#include "cachelab.h"

/* Always use a 64-bit variable to hold memory addresses*/
typedef unsigned long long int mem_addr_t;

/* a struct that groups cache parameters together */
typedef struct {
    int s; /* 2**s cache sets */
    int b; /* cacheline block size 2**b bytes */
    int E; /* number of cachelines per set */
    int S; /* number of sets, derived from S = 2**s */
    int B; /* cacheline block size (bytes), derived from B = 2**b */
} cache_param_t;

int verbosity;

/*
 * printUsage - Print usage info
 */
void printUsage(char* argv[])
{
    printf("Usage: %s [-hv] -s <num> -E <num> -b <num> -t <file>\n", argv[0]);
    printf("Options:\n");
    printf("  -h         Print this help message.\n");
    printf("  -v         Optional verbose flag.\n");
    printf("  -s <num>   Number of set index bits.\n");
    printf("  -E <num>   Number of lines per set.\n");
    printf("  -b <num>   Number of block offset bits.\n");
    printf("  -t <file>  Trace file.\n");
    printf("\nExamples:\n");
    printf("  %s -s 4 -E 1 -b 4 -t traces/yi.trace\n", argv[0]);
    printf("  %s -v -s 8 -E 2 -b 4 -t traces/yi.trace\n", argv[0]);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    cache_param_t par;
    bzero(&par, sizeof(par));

    char *trace_file;
    char c;
    while( (c=getopt(argc,argv,"s:E:b:t:vh")) != -1){
        switch(c){
        case 's':
            par.s = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'E':
            par.E = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'b':
            par.b = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 't':
            trace_file = optarg;
            break;
        case 'v':
            verbosity = 1;
            break;
        case 'h':
            printUsage(argv);
            exit(0);
        default:
            printUsage(argv);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    if (par.s == 0 || par.E == 0 || par.b == 0 || trace_file == NULL) {
        printf("%s: Missing required command line argument\n", argv[0]);
        printUsage(argv);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* TODO: Compute S and B based on information passed in */

    //Compute S and B, 2^s and 2^b respectively
    par.S = (1 << par.s);
    par.B = (1 << par.b);

    /* TODO: Initialize a cache */

    //Structure for a line
    typedef struct {
      int valid;
      mem_addr_t tag;
      int timestamp;
    } line_st;

    //Structure for a set; a pointer to an array of lines
    typedef struct {
      line_st *lines;
    } cache_set;

    //Structure for a cache; a pointer to an array of sets
    typedef struct {
      cache_set *sets;
    } cache_t;

    //allocate space for sets and for lines
    cache_t cache;
    cache.sets = malloc(par.S * sizeof(cache_set));
    for (int i = 0; i < par.S; i++) {
      cache.sets[i].lines = malloc(sizeof(line_st) * par.E);
    }

    //counters
    int hit_count = 0;
    int miss_count = 0;
    int eviction_count = 0;

    /* TODO: Run the trace simulation */

    char act; //L,S,M
    int size; //size read in from file
    int TSTAMP = 0; //value for LRU
    int empty = -1; //index of empty space
    int H = 0; //is there a hit
    int E = 0; //is there an eviction
    int toEvict = 0; //keeps track of what to evict
    mem_addr_t addr;

    //open the file and read it in
    FILE * traceFile = fopen(trace_file, "r");
    if (traceFile != NULL) {

      //keep going while we have additional lines
      //while(feof(traceFile) == 0) {
        while(fscanf(traceFile, " %c %llx,%d", &act, &addr, &size) == 3){
        if (act != 'I') {
        //read the next line and look for string formated as " %c %llx,%d"

        //sscanf(traceFile, " %c %llx,%d", &act, &addr, &size);
        //fscanf(traceFile, " %c %llx,%d", &act, &addr, &size);

        //calculate address tag and set index
        mem_addr_t addr_tag = addr >> (par.s + par.b);
        int tag_size = (64 - (par.s + par.b));
        unsigned long long temp = addr << (tag_size);
        unsigned long long setid = temp >> (tag_size + par.b);

        //unsigned long long setid = ((addr >> par.b) & (par.S - 1));
        cache_set set = cache.sets[setid];
        int low = par.E + 1;
        for(int e = 0; e < par.E; e++) {
          if (set.lines[e].valid == 0) {
        empty = e;
          }
          else if (set.lines[e].valid == 1){
        if (TSTAMP < low) {
          low = TSTAMP;
          toEvict = e;
        }
        if (set.lines[e].tag == addr_tag) {
          hit_count++;
          H = 1;
          set.lines[e].timestamp = TSTAMP;
          TSTAMP++;
        }
          }
        }
        //if we have a miss
        if (H != 1){
          miss_count++;
          //if we have an empty line
          if (empty > -1) {
        set.lines[empty].valid = 1;
        set.lines[empty].tag = addr_tag;
        set.lines[empty].timestamp = TSTAMP;
        TSTAMP++;
          }
          //if the set is full we need to evict
          else if (empty < 0) {
        E = 1;
        set.lines[toEvict].tag = addr_tag;
        set.lines[toEvict].timestamp = TSTAMP;
        eviction_count++;
          }
        }
        //if the instruction is M, we will always get a hit
        if (act == 'M') {
          hit_count++;
        }
        //if the -v flag is set print out all debug information
        if (verbosity == 1) {
          printf("%c ", act);
          //printf("%llx,%d ", addr_tag, setid);
          printf("%llx,%d ", addr, size);
          if (H == 1) {
        printf("Hit ");
          }
          else if (H != 1) {
        printf("Miss ");
          }
          if (E == 1) {
        printf("Eviction ");
          }
          if (act == 'M') {
        printf("Hit ");
          }
          printf("\n");
        }
        empty = -1;
        H = 0;
        E = 0;
      }
      }
    }

    /* TODO: Clean up cache resources */

    /* TODO: Print out real results */
    printSummary(hit_count, miss_count, eviction_count);
    return 0;
}
```

I am running my code with the following sample input:

```
 S 00600aa0,1
 S 7ff000384,4
 L 7ff000384,4
 L 7ff000384,4
 L 00600a20,4
 L 7ff000384,4
```

My code produces the following result:

```
./ -v -s 2 -E 2 -b 3 -t traces/test.trace
S 600aa0,1 Miss 
S 7ff000384,4 Miss 
L 7ff000384,4 Hit 
L 7ff000384,4 Hit 
L 600a20,4 Miss Eviction 
L 7ff000384,4 Miss Eviction 
hits:2 misses:4 evictions:2
```

but this is what it should be producing:

```
./ -v -s 2 -E 2 -b 3 -t traces/test.trace
S 600aa0,1 miss 
S 7ff000384,4 miss 
L 7ff000384,4 hit 
L 7ff000384,4 hit 
L 600a20,4 miss eviction 
L 7ff000384,4 hit 
hits:3 misses:3 evictions:1
```

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:

Second test file:

```
 S 00600aa0,1
I  004005b6,5
I  004005bb,5
I  004005c0,5
 S 7ff000398,8
I  0040051e,1
 S 7ff000390,8
I  0040051f,3
I  00400522,4
 S 7ff000378,8
I  00400526,4
 S 7ff000370,8
I  0040052a,7
 S 7ff000384,4
I  00400531,2
I  00400581,4
 L 7ff000384,4
I  00400585,2
I  00400533,7
 S 7ff000388,4
I  0040053a,2
I  00400577,4
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040057b,2
I  0040053c,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040053f,2
I  00400541,4
I  00400545,3
I  00400548,4
 L 7ff000378,8
I  0040054c,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040054f,2
I  00400551,3
 L 00600a20,4
I  00400554,3
 S 7ff00038c,4
I  00400557,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040055a,2
I  0040055c,4
I  00400560,3
I  00400563,4
 L 7ff000370,8
I  00400567,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040056a,3
I  0040056d,3
 L 7ff00038c,4
I  00400570,3
 S 00600a60,4
I  00400573,4
 M 7ff000388,4
I  00400577,4
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040057b,2
I  0040053c,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040053f,2
I  00400541,4
I  00400545,3
I  00400548,4
 L 7ff000378,8
I  0040054c,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040054f,2
I  00400551,3
 L 00600a24,4
I  00400554,3
 S 7ff00038c,4
I  00400557,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040055a,2
I  0040055c,4
I  00400560,3
I  00400563,4
 L 7ff000370,8
I  00400567,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040056a,3
I  0040056d,3
 L 7ff00038c,4
I  00400570,3
 S 00600a70,4
I  00400573,4
 M 7ff000388,4
I  00400577,4
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040057b,2
I  0040053c,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040053f,2
I  00400541,4
I  00400545,3
I  00400548,4
 L 7ff000378,8
I  0040054c,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040054f,2
I  00400551,3
 L 00600a28,4
I  00400554,3
 S 7ff00038c,4
I  00400557,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040055a,2
I  0040055c,4
I  00400560,3
I  00400563,4
 L 7ff000370,8
I  00400567,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040056a,3
I  0040056d,3
 L 7ff00038c,4
I  00400570,3
 S 00600a80,4
I  00400573,4
 M 7ff000388,4
I  00400577,4
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040057b,2
I  0040053c,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040053f,2
I  00400541,4
I  00400545,3
I  00400548,4
 L 7ff000378,8
I  0040054c,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040054f,2
I  00400551,3
 L 00600a2c,4
I  00400554,3
 S 7ff00038c,4
I  00400557,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040055a,2
I  0040055c,4
I  00400560,3
I  00400563,4
 L 7ff000370,8
I  00400567,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040056a,3
I  0040056d,3
 L 7ff00038c,4
I  00400570,3
 S 00600a90,4
I  00400573,4
 M 7ff000388,4
I  00400577,4
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040057b,2
I  0040057d,4
 M 7ff000384,4
I  00400581,4
 L 7ff000384,4
I  00400585,2
I  00400533,7
 S 7ff000388,4
I  0040053a,2
I  00400577,4
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040057b,2
I  0040053c,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040053f,2
I  00400541,4
I  00400545,3
I  00400548,4
 L 7ff000378,8
I  0040054c,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040054f,2
I  00400551,3
 L 00600a30,4
I  00400554,3
 S 7ff00038c,4
I  00400557,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040055a,2
I  0040055c,4
I  00400560,3
I  00400563,4
 L 7ff000370,8
I  00400567,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040056a,3
I  0040056d,3
 L 7ff00038c,4
I  00400570,3
 S 00600a64,4
I  00400573,4
 M 7ff000388,4
I  00400577,4
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040057b,2
I  0040053c,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040053f,2
I  00400541,4
I  00400545,3
I  00400548,4
 L 7ff000378,8
I  0040054c,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040054f,2
I  00400551,3
 L 00600a34,4
I  00400554,3
 S 7ff00038c,4
I  00400557,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040055a,2
I  0040055c,4
I  00400560,3
I  00400563,4
 L 7ff000370,8
I  00400567,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040056a,3
I  0040056d,3
 L 7ff00038c,4
I  00400570,3
 S 00600a74,4
I  00400573,4
 M 7ff000388,4
I  00400577,4
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040057b,2
I  0040053c,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040053f,2
I  00400541,4
I  00400545,3
I  00400548,4
 L 7ff000378,8
I  0040054c,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040054f,2
I  00400551,3
 L 00600a38,4
I  00400554,3
 S 7ff00038c,4
I  00400557,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040055a,2
I  0040055c,4
I  00400560,3
I  00400563,4
 L 7ff000370,8
I  00400567,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040056a,3
I  0040056d,3
 L 7ff00038c,4
I  00400570,3
 S 00600a84,4
I  00400573,4
 M 7ff000388,4
I  00400577,4
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040057b,2
I  0040053c,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040053f,2
I  00400541,4
I  00400545,3
I  00400548,4
 L 7ff000378,8
I  0040054c,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040054f,2
I  00400551,3
 L 00600a3c,4
I  00400554,3
 S 7ff00038c,4
I  00400557,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040055a,2
I  0040055c,4
I  00400560,3
I  00400563,4
 L 7ff000370,8
I  00400567,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040056a,3
I  0040056d,3
 L 7ff00038c,4
I  00400570,3
 S 00600a94,4
I  00400573,4
 M 7ff000388,4
I  00400577,4
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040057b,2
I  0040057d,4
 M 7ff000384,4
I  00400581,4
 L 7ff000384,4
I  00400585,2
I  00400533,7
 S 7ff000388,4
I  0040053a,2
I  00400577,4
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040057b,2
I  0040053c,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040053f,2
I  00400541,4
I  00400545,3
I  00400548,4
 L 7ff000378,8
I  0040054c,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040054f,2
I  00400551,3
 L 00600a40,4
I  00400554,3
 S 7ff00038c,4
I  00400557,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040055a,2
I  0040055c,4
I  00400560,3
I  00400563,4
 L 7ff000370,8
I  00400567,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040056a,3
I  0040056d,3
 L 7ff00038c,4
I  00400570,3
 S 00600a68,4
I  00400573,4
 M 7ff000388,4
I  00400577,4
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040057b,2
I  0040053c,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040053f,2
I  00400541,4
I  00400545,3
I  00400548,4
 L 7ff000378,8
I  0040054c,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040054f,2
I  00400551,3
 L 00600a44,4
I  00400554,3
 S 7ff00038c,4
I  00400557,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040055a,2
I  0040055c,4
I  00400560,3
I  00400563,4
 L 7ff000370,8
I  00400567,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040056a,3
I  0040056d,3
 L 7ff00038c,4
I  00400570,3
 S 00600a78,4
I  00400573,4
 M 7ff000388,4
I  00400577,4
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040057b,2
I  0040053c,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040053f,2
I  00400541,4
I  00400545,3
I  00400548,4
 L 7ff000378,8
I  0040054c,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040054f,2
I  00400551,3
 L 00600a48,4
I  00400554,3
 S 7ff00038c,4
I  00400557,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040055a,2
I  0040055c,4
I  00400560,3
I  00400563,4
 L 7ff000370,8
I  00400567,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040056a,3
I  0040056d,3
 L 7ff00038c,4
I  00400570,3
 S 00600a88,4
I  00400573,4
 M 7ff000388,4
I  00400577,4
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040057b,2
I  0040053c,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040053f,2
I  00400541,4
I  00400545,3
I  00400548,4
 L 7ff000378,8
I  0040054c,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040054f,2
I  00400551,3
 L 00600a4c,4
I  00400554,3
 S 7ff00038c,4
I  00400557,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040055a,2
I  0040055c,4
I  00400560,3
I  00400563,4
 L 7ff000370,8
I  00400567,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040056a,3
I  0040056d,3
 L 7ff00038c,4
I  00400570,3
 S 00600a98,4
I  00400573,4
 M 7ff000388,4
I  00400577,4
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040057b,2
I  0040057d,4
 M 7ff000384,4
I  00400581,4
 L 7ff000384,4
I  00400585,2
I  00400533,7
 S 7ff000388,4
I  0040053a,2
I  00400577,4
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040057b,2
I  0040053c,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040053f,2
I  00400541,4
I  00400545,3
I  00400548,4
 L 7ff000378,8
I  0040054c,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040054f,2
I  00400551,3
 L 00600a50,4
I  00400554,3
 S 7ff00038c,4
I  00400557,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040055a,2
I  0040055c,4
I  00400560,3
I  00400563,4
 L 7ff000370,8
I  00400567,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040056a,3
I  0040056d,3
 L 7ff00038c,4
I  00400570,3
 S 00600a6c,4
I  00400573,4
 M 7ff000388,4
I  00400577,4
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040057b,2
I  0040053c,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040053f,2
I  00400541,4
I  00400545,3
I  00400548,4
 L 7ff000378,8
I  0040054c,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040054f,2
I  00400551,3
 L 00600a54,4
I  00400554,3
 S 7ff00038c,4
I  00400557,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040055a,2
I  0040055c,4
I  00400560,3
I  00400563,4
 L 7ff000370,8
I  00400567,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040056a,3
I  0040056d,3
 L 7ff00038c,4
I  00400570,3
 S 00600a7c,4
I  00400573,4
 M 7ff000388,4
I  00400577,4
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040057b,2
I  0040053c,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040053f,2
I  00400541,4
I  00400545,3
I  00400548,4
 L 7ff000378,8
I  0040054c,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040054f,2
I  00400551,3
 L 00600a58,4
I  00400554,3
 S 7ff00038c,4
I  00400557,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040055a,2
I  0040055c,4
I  00400560,3
I  00400563,4
 L 7ff000370,8
I  00400567,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040056a,3
I  0040056d,3
 L 7ff00038c,4
I  00400570,3
 S 00600a8c,4
I  00400573,4
 M 7ff000388,4
I  00400577,4
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040057b,2
I  0040053c,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040053f,2
I  00400541,4
I  00400545,3
I  00400548,4
 L 7ff000378,8
I  0040054c,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040054f,2
I  00400551,3
 L 00600a5c,4
I  00400554,3
 S 7ff00038c,4
I  00400557,3
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040055a,2
I  0040055c,4
I  00400560,3
I  00400563,4
 L 7ff000370,8
I  00400567,3
 L 7ff000384,4
I  0040056a,3
I  0040056d,3
 L 7ff00038c,4
I  00400570,3
 S 00600a9c,4
I  00400573,4
 M 7ff000388,4
I  00400577,4
 L 7ff000388,4
I  0040057b,2
I  0040057d,4
 M 7ff000384,4
I  00400581,4
 L 7ff000384,4
I  00400585,2
I  00400587,1
 L 7ff000390,8
I  00400588,1
 L 7ff000398,8
I  004005c5,7
 L 00600aa0,1
```

Expected Values:

```
              My simulator       Reference simulator
(s,E,b)    Hits  Misses  Evicts    Hits  Misses  Evicts
(2,2,3)     196      42      34     201      37      29  
(2,4,3)     208      30      14     212      26      10
```

Comment: Hey @Lesha, your post here really helped me with the C sim assignment, I was wondering if you ever also had a malloc lab at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky bug there.  I changed the for-loop in the middle to only set `empty` if it is already -1, so it will use the first empty spot found, then it won't change it again once it has found an empty spot.  I also modified the initialization of `low` to be INT_MAX and look for true least-recently used by changing the relevant `else` conditions.  I also re-ordered the code to look for a match BEFORE looking for eviction candidates, since finding a match freshens the cache timestamp.  You also had forgotten to increment TSTAMP in the case of a Miss Eviction.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <limits.h>

//#include "cachelab.h"

/* Always use a 64-bit variable to hold memory addresses*/
typedef unsigned long long int mem_addr_t;

/* a struct that groups cache parameters together */
typedef struct
{
   int s;                       /* 2**s cache sets */
   int b;                       /* cacheline block size 2**b bytes */
   int E;                       /* number of cachelines per set */
   int S;                       /* number of sets, derived from S = 2**s */
   int B;                       /* cacheline block size (bytes), derived from B = 2**b */
} cache_param_t;

int verbosity;

/* printUsage - Print usage info */
void printUsage( char *argv[] )
{
   printf( "Usage: %s [-hv] -s <num> -E <num> -b <num> -t <file>\n", argv[0] );
   printf( "Options:\n" );
   printf( "  -h         Print this help message.\n" );
   printf( "  -v         Optional verbose flag.\n" );
   printf( "  -s <num>   Number of set index bits.\n" );
   printf( "  -E <num>   Number of lines per set.\n" );
   printf( "  -b <num>   Number of block offset bits.\n" );
   printf( "  -t <file>  Trace file.\n" );
   printf( "\nExamples:\n" );
   printf( "  %s -s 4 -E 1 -b 4 -t traces/yi.trace\n", argv[0] );
   printf( "  %s -v -s 8 -E 2 -b 4 -t traces/yi.trace\n", argv[0] );
   exit( 0 );
}

void printSummary( int hit_count, int miss_count, int eviction_count )
{
   printf( "hits: %d   misses: %d   evictions: %d\n", hit_count, miss_count, eviction_count );
} 

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
   cache_param_t par;

   bzero( &par, sizeof ( par ) );

   char *trace_file;
   char c;

   while ( ( c = getopt( argc, argv, "s:E:b:t:vh" ) ) != -1 )
   {
      switch ( c )
      {
         case 's':
            par.s = atoi( optarg );
            break;
         case 'E':
            par.E = atoi( optarg );
            break;
         case 'b':
            par.b = atoi( optarg );
            break;
         case 't':
            trace_file = optarg;
            break;
         case 'v':
            verbosity = 1;
            break;
         case 'h':
            printUsage( argv );
            exit( 0 );
         default:
            printUsage( argv );
            exit( 1 );
      }
   }

   if ( par.s == 0 || par.E == 0 || par.b == 0 || trace_file == NULL )
   {
      printf( "%s: Missing required command line argument\n", argv[0] );
      printUsage( argv );
      exit( 1 );
   }

   /* TODO: Compute S and B based on information passed in */

   //Compute S and B, 2^s and 2^b respectively
   par.S = ( 1 << par.s );
   par.B = ( 1 << par.b );

   /* TODO: Initialize a cache */

   //Structure for a line
   typedef struct
   {
      int valid;
      mem_addr_t tag;
      int timestamp;
   } line_st;

   //Structure for a set; a pointer to an array of lines
   typedef struct
   {
      line_st *lines;
   } cache_set;

   //Structure for a cache; a pointer to an array of sets
   typedef struct
   {
      cache_set *sets;
   } cache_t;

   //allocate space for sets and for lines
   cache_t cache;

   cache.sets = malloc( par.S * sizeof ( cache_set ) );
   for ( int i = 0; i < par.S; i++ )
   {
      cache.sets[i].lines = malloc( sizeof ( line_st ) * par.E );
   }

   //counters
   int hit_count = 0;
   int miss_count = 0;
   int eviction_count = 0;

   /* TODO: Run the trace simulation */

   char act;                    //L,S,M
   int size;                    //size read in from file
   int TSTAMP = 0;              //value for LRU
   int empty = -1;              //index of empty space
   int H = 0;                   //is there a hit
   int E = 0;                   //is there an eviction
   mem_addr_t addr;

   //open the file and read it in
   FILE *traceFile = fopen( trace_file, "r" );

   if ( traceFile != NULL )
   {
      while ( fscanf( traceFile, " %c %llx,%d", &act, &addr, &size ) == 3 )
      {
         int toEvict = 0;             //keeps track of what to evict
         if ( act != 'I' )
         {
            //calculate address tag and set index
            mem_addr_t addr_tag = addr >> ( par.s + par.b );
            int tag_size = ( 64 - ( par.s + par.b ) );
            unsigned long long temp = addr << ( tag_size );
            unsigned long long setid = temp >> ( tag_size + par.b );
            cache_set set = cache.sets[setid];
            int low = INT_MAX; // CHANGED, also added #include <limits.h>

            for ( int e = 0; e < par.E; e++ ) {
               if ( set.lines[e].valid == 1 ) {
                  // CHANGED ORDER: look for hit before eviction candidates
                  if ( set.lines[e].tag == addr_tag ) {
                     hit_count++;
                     H = 1;
                     set.lines[e].timestamp = TSTAMP;
                     TSTAMP++;
                  }
                  // CHANGED WHOLE ELSE: look for oldest for eviction.
                  else if ( set.lines[e].timestamp < low ) {
                     low = set.lines[e].timestamp;
                     toEvict = e;
                  }
               }
               // CHANGED: if we haven't yet found an empty, mark one that we found.
               else if( empty == -1 ) {
                  empty = e;
               }
            }

            //if we have a miss
            if ( H != 1 )
            {
               miss_count++;
               //if we have an empty line
               if ( empty > -1 )
               {
                  set.lines[empty].valid = 1;
                  set.lines[empty].tag = addr_tag;
                  set.lines[empty].timestamp = TSTAMP;
                  TSTAMP++; 
               }
               //if the set is full we need to evict
               else if ( empty < 0 )
               {
                  E = 1;
                  set.lines[toEvict].tag = addr_tag;
                  set.lines[toEvict].timestamp = TSTAMP;
                  TSTAMP++; // CHANGED: increment TSTAMP here too
                  eviction_count++;
               }
            }
            //if the instruction is M, we will always get a hit
            if ( act == 'M' )
            {
               hit_count++;
            }
            //if the -v flag is set print out all debug information
            if ( verbosity == 1 )
            {
               printf( "%c ", act );
               printf( "%llx,%d", addr, size );
               if ( H == 1 )
               {
                  printf( "Hit " );
               }
               else if ( H != 1 )
               {
                  printf( "Miss " );
               }
               if ( E == 1 )
               {
                  printf( "Eviction " );
               }
               // CHANGED: don't print Hit again since 'M' is always going to print Hit above.
               printf( "\n" );
            }
            empty = -1;
            H = 0;
            E = 0;
         }
      }
   }

   /* TODO: Clean up cache resources */

   /* TODO: Print out real results */
   printSummary( hit_count, miss_count, eviction_count );
   return 0;
}
```

My results:

```
$ ./ca2 -s 2 -E 2 -b 3 -t f2.trace
hits: 201   misses: 37   evictions: 29
$ ./ca2 -s 2 -E 4 -b 3 -t f2.trace
hits: 212   misses: 26   evictions: 10
```

Comment: I've tried implementing your fix but im still getting the same incorrect output as before.

The problem is with the end of the output, my program reports L 7ff000384,4 as miss eviction, but it should be registering this as a hit. But Im not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Oddly enough even when using your whole file I am getting the old result and not what is expected. Is it possible that some environment difference is causing this problem?

Comment: I changed the order of the last two lines in the input and the problem disappeared. I think the first "Miss Eviction " somehow causes a second one. Any idea what could be causing this to happen?

Comment: I've made the changes as you recommended. It works for this sample input but once run with different sample input reports incorrect counts. The data write out sometimes writes " Miss Eviction Hit" which is not possible and I assume causing the error. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I've added the full test file I am using to the original post. Output should be `hits:201 misses:37 evictions:29` but my program prints `hits:196 misses:42 evictions:34`

Comment: What does 'L' 'S' and 'M' mean for actions?

Comment: If I run `./ca -v -s 2 -E 3 -b 3 -t file2.trace`  (note -E 3 instead of -E 2) my code gives the answer: `hits: 201   misses: 37   evictions: 25`  If I use -E 2, I get the same answer you get.  What command line is supposed to be used with the second file?

Comment: The operation field denotes the type of memory access: “I” denotes an instruction load, “L” a data load, “S” a data store, and “M” a data modify (i.e., a data load followed by a data store)

Comment: I've added the values of s E and b to use as well as the values they are expected to return vs what my simulation is returning. I've added it to the end of the original post because I could not format it correctly in a comment. The simulator works for all cases except those two (both of which rely on the same trace file).

Comment: The first case has 5 fewer hits and 5 extra misses and evictions, the second case is the same thing with 4. This makes me think that somewhere hits are still being reported as "miss eviction " leading to incorrect total counts.

Comment: I updated my version of the code, a few more bug fixes.  Please re-read my comment before the code, and look for the tag "CHANGED" in the code for areas changed.